# How to search for the nth occurence of a pattern in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am trying to avoid elisp as much as possible. I think I am able to implement a solution to my problem in Elisp, but that's not what I am looking for.

I am looking for the nth occurence of a string in a buffer.
For instance looking after the 4th occurence of `foo`, I've tried <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> `foo`. But `C-s` does not interpret prefixes.

Is there a simple/elegant key sequence in Emacs to perform that job?

Comment: Try keyboard macros. They may be enough for the job.

Comment: e.g.: `C-x ( C-s foo RET C-x ) C-u C-x e` (or use `<f3>` and `<f4>`, but `C-u <f4>` means something different, so you'd need to be explicit with `C-u 4 <f4>` or `M-4 <f4>`, etc...)

Comment: Keyboard macros worked for me. You should turn that into an answer, especially since the question was for a non-elisp solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`search-forward` is a simple function to search the next occurrence of a string. It also accepts an optional `COUNT` argument searching for the next `COUNT` successive occurrences.

Unfortunately you cannot call it with a prefix argument, because it queries for input.

You already guessed the answer: throw together some elisp.

This function queries you for a string and a count and performs the search:

```
(defun search-forward-count (string count)
  (interactive "sString: \nnCount: ")
  (re-search-forward string nil nil count))
```

This function queries you for a string and uses the prefix argument as its count:

```
(defun search-forward-prefix (count string)
  (interactive "p\nsString: ")
  (re-search-forward string nil nil count))
```

Comment: This is elegant/simple in my book. Your opinion might vary

Comment: I would assume the poster would want a prefix arg, just flip your arguments and use this interactive form (interactive "p\nsString: ")