# Find the Nth item in a buffer?

Tags: emacs

From a log/error message I know the 32nd occurrence of a string in a file has a problem. But I do not know the line number. I could use `grep` but I already have the file open in emacs.

Looking in the docs, I see that `search-foreward` and `search-forward-regexp` takes the repeat count as the final parameter. But I cannot see a way to invoke it directly. I really quickly tossed this together:

```
(defun my/find-nth (str num)
  (interactive "MString: \nNCount: ")
  (search-forward str nil nil num))
```

But I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: You are not missing something, you cannot specify that arg interactively without a wrapper function. See this thread for how to specify it with a prefix arg in your wrapper which is generally easier and more emacsy.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837135/how-to-search-for-the-nth-occurence-of-a-pattern-in-emacs

Comment: Thanks @JordonBiondo. I did look around before posting but I found this to be a hard thing to search for (the irony...). Good point about taking a prefix argument. Looks like I will put this function in my tool chest and keep moving.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `occur`, and then jump directly to the 32nd occurrence:

```
M-x occur
type your regexp, then RET
M-32 M-g M-n
```

The last command calls `next-error` 32 times, landing you on the 32nd occurrence of the regexp in the file.

Comment: occur worked as advertised. I needed to type C-u 32 C-x ` to get to the 32nd entry. C-x ` being bound to ``next-error``. occur was really slow with the 6MB 88,298 line long XML file I am working on. It took nearly 15 seconds for the result buffer to appear. My little helper using ``search-forward`` was nearly instant.

Comment: While I like this suggestion it is not exactly the right solution. In this case I just want to go to a particular section of the buffer. I do not need the second buffer containing all of the search matches since I am unlikely to bounce around further. Thank you for the introduction to ``occur`` though. it is a useful tool.